# Is it possible to run phantomjs by using IE desired capabilities?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

By default phantomjs uses chrome capabilities. Is it possible to run it with IE capabilities .If so, I need to use it for page-object gem like:

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs, args: '--ignore-ssl-errors=true')
```

Can any body please provide me any solution for it.

Comment: So you want phantomjs, a Webkit browser, to behave like IE? Why don't you use the IE watir webdriver?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I need to run the testcases in headless mode without lunching browser and behave like IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is no: Phantom is using the same WebKit rendering engine that Chrome/Safari uses (*), so cannot act like IE.

You might be interested in [TrifleJS](http://triflejs.org/) which is a headless IE port of PhantomJS. (The project is in the early stages, and (AFAIK) [won't work with CasperJS yet](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/688), and [does not seem to support selenium integration](https://github.com/sdesalas/trifleJS/issues/20) either yet.)

*: More precisely, Phantom 1.9 is equivalent to about Chrome 13. And recent versions of Chrome use Blink, not WebKit. So Phantom 2.x, when finally released, won't be equivalent to any version of Chrome.